# Head revision not working as intended for Google Docs formats

Tags: google-drive-api

For "native" Google documents (maybe it applies to all Google formats, I haven't checked), using head in the [revisions.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/get) method returns the first revision instead of the latest one. It seems that it only relies on the order of the revisions returned by the [revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/revisions/list) method, and that order is not really uniform (e.g. a Google document lists the latest first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug, I managed to reproduce it. I reported it to the engineers and I'll update this answer as soon I hear back from them.

UPDATE 12/2: this is now fixed and the fix will be live in 1-2 weeks

Comment: Is the fix live? Should it fix also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913860/google-drive-sdk-not-returning-headrevisionid-for-google-docs-format In the case that the linked question describes, I'm still seeing `null` as the headRevisionId.