# Listing revisions of Google-format files not working as intended

Tags: google-drive-api

At first it seemed like we were encountering a bug similar to the one reported at [Head revision not working as intended for Google Docs formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410459/head-revision-not-working-as-intended-for-google-docs-formats), but upon further investigation it seems to be a different one.

Google-format files (documents, spreadsheets, etc.) seem to collapse revisions once the number of revisions for a file exceeds a certain limit, and the API seems to return the collapsed set of revisions instead of the full set (i.e., the set shown after clicking "Show less detailed revisions" when viewing the file on the Drive web app).

However, the API returns the *earliest* revision in each set instead of the latest one. So when trying to retrieve the latest revision (either via revisions.list or using 'head' in revisions.get), it often doesn't return the actual latest revision, but instead the first revision in the latest collapsed set.

Here's the ID of a public spreadsheet that demonstrates this behavior: 0AgbOJk17djyxdGFqZzlRTks2NnNidzRzRGVJWFlDU2c

In this particular case, revision ID 1365416326903000 is returned as the "latest", even though there are many later revisions.

Comment: Revision merging is an expected behavior, but the revision should be latest of the merged group. I'm going to take a look at this issue in detail.

Comment: As a note, even though you made later changes after `1365416326903000 `, those changes are being merged into `1365416326903000`. Take a look at https://gist.github.com/burcu/3fb44a6d3ba5fdfc3b5e, I made several changes to a single file and create a new revision on each update. They have been all merged into revision `0ByfSjdPVs9MZRWE3YndEc1pyOVBKYUhtR2dNeXlVV0lIWWlRPQ`. This should be the expected behavior.

Comment: @BurcuDogan I'm not sure I understand your note regarding expected merging behavior. Does the ID for the latest revision (group) not change, and only the metadata and contents? I would've expected a new revision ID to be created, possibly replacing an earlier one in its revision group.

Comment: we'll discuss the issue internally. I'm agree with you that it's a weird behavior not to provide a new revision ID.